# Custom error_messages during the form validation when using generic edit UpdateView

Tags: python, django

The solution I currently use for custom error_messages during the form validation when using generic edit UpdateView is as follows

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class Employee(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Name")
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name="Surname")
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Birthday")
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Employee

class ModelFormWithCustomErrorMessages(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Employee
        fields = '__all__'
        error_messages = {'date_of_birth': {'invalid': 'Custom invalid error message'}}
```

views.py:

```
from .models import Employee
from .forms import ModelFormWithCustomErrorMessages

class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = ModelFormWithCustomErrorMessages
```

The thing I don't really like here is that you have to create separate ModelForm (ModelFormWithCustomErrorMessages) for every model where you want to cusomize error_messages.

Just adding an argument error_messages for the model field doesn't work for the forms:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, error_messages={'invalid': 'Custom invalid error message'})
```

Is there a better way to customize error_messages when using generic edit views?

Comment: Can you give an example of an error that passes through the form to your model that you want to customize the error message for? This can help

Comment: @MadeOfAir. You're right, I don't really need model field validation in my case. modelform_factory() is a good way out, cause using it you don't have to create extra form just for customizing error messages. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the [`modelform_factory()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) function, maybe like this:

```
from django import forms

class EmployeeUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Employee
    form_class = forms.modelform_factory(
        model=Employee,
        fields='__all__',
        error_messages={
            'date_of_birth': {'invalid': 'Custom invalid error message'},
        })
```

And yes, the models error messages are only used in [specific situations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#considerations-regarding-model-errormessages), like the docs mention.